# Theorems helpful for largest-eigenvalue lower bound of correlation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics

Need suggestion of theorems for **lower** bound of the largest eigenvalue of the correlation matrix (symmetric, diagonal all being one, all other values in **range** $[-1,1]$).

Of course the eigenvalue has to be non-negative since the matrix is positive semi-definite, but need help with a tighter lower bound.

Comment: If it's an $n\times n$ matrix where every entry has modulus at most $1$, then the largest eigenvalue is at most $n$.  This is attained when every entry is $1$.

Answer (score 0):

(Completely modified answer)

Correlation matrix $C$ being semi-definite positive, its eigenvalues are : $0 \leq \lambda_1 \leq \cdots \leq \lambda_n.$

The trace of $C$ being $n$, we thus have: $\lambda_n \geq 1$.

This bound $1$ is attained each time $C=I_n$ (identity matrix), for example by taking any pair of independently generated $n$-dimensional vectors.

> Thus $1$ is the answer to your question.

Comment: First, thank you for your answer. Second, maybe I misunderstood your answer, but I stated "all other values in $[-1,1]$", i.e. the matrix is not ${\bf 1}^T{\bf 1}$, which is a special case.

Comment: I have understood that all other values values are in $[-1,1]$, but I realize now that I have misunderstood that you wanted a lower bound for $\max \lambda_k$. This lower bound is 1. I modify my answer

Comment: Correction done. Sorry for having misunderstood your question...